# DPDK function has different output when called from Rust than from C

Tags: c, rust, ffi, dpdk

I'm writing a Rust program that interfaces with Intel's DPDK and I've run into an issue I do not quite grasp. I can currently execute a function from the DPDK library in a Rust program but it differs in results from the same program written in C.

Rust program output -

```
~/Dev/rust_eal_init_test$ sudo target/debug/rust_eal_init_test 
EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-2048kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
~/Dev/rust_eal_init_test$
```

C program output -

```
~/Dev/c_eal_init_test$ sudo build/c_eal_init_test 
EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-2048kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
PMD: bnxt_rte_pmd_init() called for (null)
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:19.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:153a rte_em_pmd
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1533 rte_igb_pmd
~/Dev/c_eal_init_test$
```

DPDK has been compiled as static libraries that I am linking to in Rust. Below is the code for both the Rust and C program.

Rust main.rs -

```
extern crate libc;

use std::env;
use std::process::exit;
use std::ffi::CString;
use libc::{c_int, c_char,};

extern {
    pub fn rte_eal_init(argc: c_int, argv: *mut *mut c_char) -> c_int;
}

// librte_eal
pub fn dpdk_rte_eal_init(argc: i32, argv: Vec<String>) -> i32 {
    let mut args: Vec<*mut c_char> = argv.iter().map(|x| CString::new(x.clone()).unwrap().into_raw()).collect();
    let retc: c_int = unsafe { rte_eal_init(argc as c_int, args.as_mut_ptr()) };
    let ret: i32 = retc as i32;
    ret
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let ret: i32 = dpdk_rte_eal_init(args.len() as i32, args);
    if ret < 0 {
        exit(ret);
    }
}
```

C main.c -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <rte_eal.h>
#include <rte_debug.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;

    ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
    if (ret < 0)
        rte_panic("Cannot init EAL\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I've done some investigation by looking through the DPDK source and adding print statements to see where things differ. The `rte_eal_init()` function is in **eal.c** and calls various other init functions. The trigger for the extra output is from another function called `rte_eal_dev_init()` in **eal_common_dev.c**.

`rte_eal_dev_init()` -

```
int
rte_eal_dev_init(void)
{
    struct rte_devargs *devargs;
    struct rte_driver *driver;

    /*
     * Note that the dev_driver_list is populated here
     * from calls made to rte_eal_driver_register from constructor functions
     * embedded into PMD modules via the PMD_REGISTER_DRIVER macro
     */

    /* call the init function for each virtual device */
    TAILQ_FOREACH(devargs, &devargs_list, next) {

        if (devargs->type != RTE_DEVTYPE_VIRTUAL)
            continue;

        if (rte_eal_vdev_init(devargs->virt.drv_name,
                    devargs->args)) {
            RTE_LOG(ERR, EAL, "failed to initialize %s device\n",
                    devargs->virt.drv_name);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /* Once the vdevs are initalized, start calling all the pdev drivers */
    TAILQ_FOREACH(driver, &dev_driver_list, next) {
        if (driver->type != PMD_PDEV)
            continue;
        /* PDEV drivers don't get passed any parameters */
        driver->init(NULL, NULL);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

I've found that the Rust program enters the `rte_eal_dev_init()` function, but never enters the loop for the `TAILQ_FOREACH()` macro. If I were to add a print statement directly above and under the macro like so -

```
printf("Test before TAILQ_FOREACH\n");  
TAILQ_FOREACH(driver, &dev_driver_list, next) {
    printf("Test in TAILQ_FOREACH\n");
    if (driver->type != PMD_PDEV)
        continue;
    /* PDEV drivers don't get passed any parameters */
    driver->init(NULL, NULL);
}
```

This gives me the following output in Rust -

```
~/Dev/rust_eal_init_test$ sudo target/debug/rust_eal_init_test 
EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-2048kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
Test before TAILQ_FOREACH
~/Dev/rust_eal_init_test$
```

And the following output in C -

```
~/Dev/c_eal_init_test$ sudo build/c_eal_init_test 
EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-2048kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
Test before TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
PMD: bnxt_rte_pmd_init() called for (null)
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:19.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:153a rte_em_pmd
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1533 rte_igb_pmd
~/Dev/c_eal_init_test$
```

I found that `TAILQ_FOREACH()` is defined in **sys/queue.h**. As I understand it, linking to a static library shouldn't cause problems with the library linking to something else dynamically. Is this correct?

Comment: It sounds like you may not have converted `TAIL_Q_FOREACH`, which is presumably a macro thar generates a loop, into Rust - but you haven't shown any of the code so can't tell. I wouldn't expect it's a linking issue if you got it to run.

Comment: As currently written, this question should be closed because: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.* [edit] your question to produce a [MCVE].

Comment: Your `printf` **completely changes the behavior of the loop**. This is why braces on if statements should be mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for the input Shepmaster, I'll try and edit this today to match the rules.

Comment: Hopefully the edits I made conform to Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally thought that I was not properly linking to something that supplied the info for **sys/queue.h**. While attempting to understand linking better, I changed my build.rs for the link to DPDK from this -

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=rte_eal");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=<Path to RTE_SDK>/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib");
}
```

To this -

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=dpdk");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=<Path to RTE_SDK>/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib");
}
```

Rust now links to all DPDK libraries that get compiled instead of just **rte_eal** where the initial function is called from. Now when I execute my Rust program, I get the same output as the C program -

```
~/Dev/rust_eal_init_test$ sudo target/debug/rust_eal_init_test 
EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-2048kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
Test before TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
PMD: bnxt_rte_pmd_init() called for (null)
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
Test in TAILQ_FOREACH
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:19.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:153a rte_em_pmd
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1533 rte_igb_pmd
~/Dev/rust_eal_init_test$
```

I didn't think of one of the static libraries needing another to be included in the executable for it to function. I'm also assuming from this that if I were to compile DPDK as a shared library I wouldn't have had this issue.

Thanks to Shepmaster as well, while not directly answering my question, forcing me to simplify it made it much easier to troubleshoot my problem in a more controlled way.

Answer (score -1):

You indented the `continue` after the `if`, which is a visual hint that it is supposed to be part of the `if` block - but the compiler does not take visual hints.

You need to put `{}` around the block of the `if`, or the 'continue' will be *always* executed;

```
if (driver->type != PMD_PDEV)
{
    printf("\nDriver name = %s", driver->name); // Added to track problem
    continue;
}
```

As for the differing results - maybe C is just faster, so each core comes back and is done before the next one even gets started; whereas in Rust it is slower so they work in parallel and come back in random sequence?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the underlying question of why the Rust version's output differs from the C version. According to the narrative, the output differed *before* the broken `continue` statement was added.

Comment: I don't believe the question is around the ordering of the results, but around the missing lines (like `bnxt_rte_pmd_init` or `probe driver`), although I appreciate the subtle attempt to slander a non-C / C++ language .